# Hive overwrite table with new s3 location

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, insert, overwrite

I have a hive external table point to a location on s3. My requirement is I will be uploading a new file to this s3 location everyday and the data in my hive table should be overwritten.

Every day my script will create a folder under 's3://employee-data/' and place a csv file there. 
eg. s3://employee-data/20190812/employee_data.csv

Now I want my hive table to pick up this new file under new folder everyday and overwrite the existing data. I can get the folder name -  '20190812' through my ETL.

Can someone help.

I tried ALTER table set location 'new location'. However, this does not overwrite the data.

```
    create external table employee
    {
        name String,
        hours_worked Integer
    }
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION 's3://employee-data/';
```

Comment: what do you mean by "this does not overwrite the data" ? nothing seems to be overwritten here, the new folder is created each day and the table needs to be re-created with a new location

Comment: yes should is the correct approach to recreate the table everytime?
or can I truncate the table and alter it to point to new location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set new location and the data will be accessible:

```
ALTER table set location 's3://employee-data/20190812/';
```

This statement points table to the new location, nothing is being overwritten of course.

Or alternatively make the table partitioned:

```
create external table employee
    (
        name String,
        hours_worked Integer
    )
    partitioned by (load_date string)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION 's3://employee-data/';
```

then do [ALTER TABLE employee recover partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE));

and all dates will be mounted in separate partitions and you can query them using

```
WHERE load_date='20190812'
```

Comment: This is a good idea. But the data is not partitioned, consider it like a lookup table.